# Is there an efficient way to create android ListAdapter with each line item having a custom view?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to use a ListAdapter which can have custom view for each of the line item. For example I want a list view which looks somewhat as shown below

```
item 1 {Bold} , 
item 2 {Italics},
item 3 {Normal font}
item 4 {Normal font}
item 5 {Normal font}
```

I tried following code but what happens is if I scroll down Item 10 is also shown as bold and item 11 as italics etc which I don't want . Now after removing the caching part of the below code it works fine ( as per my expectations but seems it is a little slow .
Is there a efficient way to achieve the same

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

```
holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
if (position == 1){
holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); 
}else if ( position == 2) {
holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);    
}else if ( position == 3 ){
holder.text.setTextSize(35);
}
```

Comment: "reset" Typeface and TextSize in other cases `if(){} ... else {setup all stuff to default}` ... now it should work with caching

Comment: Found solution : You have to perform explicit checks to find out if the new font type is the one that is expected . otherwise reinflate the layout

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
if (position == 1){
   holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); 
}else if ( position == 2) {
   holder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);    
}else{
   holder.text.setTextSize(35);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are few URL to have listview with custom row::

[LINL1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)
[LINK2](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)
[LINK3](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)
[LINK4](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
[LINK5](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx)